# any() function with csv file in python not behaving how I'm expecting it to

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, any

(I'm using python 2.7 for now)
So maybe I'm not understanding how this line of code is working, because for one part of my program, it seems to be working fine, while in another part, it doesn't.

```
elif not any(user in line for line in data):
```

Basically, I have a csv file that I'm reading from and storing in the variable "data" like this:

```
f = open("scores.csv")
data = csv.reader(f)
```

the variable "user" is a string from an Entry box in Tkinter,
and the variable "line" is an arbitrary name for the for loop, just like in a piece of code that says "for i in range(69):"

So what my brain thinks that this line should do is that if it fails to find a match of user in any of the lines in the csv file, it should run the code under that statement. But it doesn't seem to do that!

However, later on in my code I try something similar:

```
elif any(user in line for line in data):
```

and this seems to work without any problems!!
I have no idea why, and I could not find anywhere on the internet of anyone else trying to do this lol.

I'm trying to make a login form as a beginner project, as I somewhat know python, so I wanted to see what I can do, but I seem to be stuck here.

I have uploaded my code to github for anyone to review:
https://github.com/Arunscape/login-form/blob/master/login.py

oh and don't worry about the "passwords" in the csv file, they're of course fake!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: it'd be ideal if you could create a minimal example that we could run to see the problem that you're describing.  As you've described it "if it fails to find a match of user in any of the lines in the csv file, it should run the code under that statement" sounds about right to me.  I _suspect_ that the problem isn't this line, but the input to this line (e.g. `data`, `user`).  But I can't know for sure without a minimal example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `data` is an iterator, not a sequence you can iterate on multiple times. After you call `any` with a generator expression iterating over `data`, some or all of the items will have been consumed. Later calls will only see what is left over (which may be nothing if the first iteration had to check all the data).

You can reproduce the issue with a much simpler bit of code:

```
iterator = iter(range(10))   # an iterator over the numbers 0 through 9

first_result = any(x == 3 for x in iterator)   # this will be True
second_result = any(x == 3 for x in iterator)  # the same expression will be False this time!
```

The first `any` call consumes (via the generator expression) the numbers `0` through `3` from the iterator. Then it stops and `any` returns `True` (stopping early in this way is known as "short circuiting").

The second `any` call only gets to consume the remaining items, it can't see the ones that were already yielded to the first `any` call. Since the iterator will only yield one `3`, the second `any` call will return `False` after consuming the rest of the numbers.

For your code to work correctly with `data` being an iterator, you can only iterate over it once.

If there are not too many values in your `csv` file, you might be better off reading all the rows into a list, which you can iterate over as many times as you want. Try:

```
data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

It might make sense to parse the data into a more meaningful data structure though, rather than a list (e.g. a dictionary mapping usernames to passwords, which you could query in `O(1)` time rather than `O(N)` time).